# How to dynamically generate variables in Action Script 2.0

Tags: actionscript, dynamic, variables

I have a for loop in action script which I'm trying to use to dynamically create variable.

Example

```
for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    var MyVar+i = i;
}
```

after this for loop runs, i would like to have 3 variables named MyVar1, MyVar2, MyVar3.  I know the code above will give you a syntax error, but that is just to illustrate what I am trying to do.  Any takers?

The primary reason i'm doing this is because I'm having scope problems noted here in this other unanswered Action Script question:  [How to pass variables into inline functions in Action Script 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713813/how-to-pass-variables-into-inline-functions-in-action-script-2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong (I haven't done AS2 for a long while), but I think you can do this using array syntax:

```
 for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    this["myVar"+i] = i;
}
```

and then for variable access:

```
var foo = this["myVar0"] //etc
```

Answer (score 1):

First answer is correct, but if you make the class dynamic (ie. new members can be created dynamically) ...

```
dynamic class ClassName { // etc. }
```

... then you can reference the variable in normal syntax:

```
var foo = this.myVar0;
```

You won't be able to access the variable at all without 'this' whether the class is dynamic or not.